# Getting 'Device <iOS simulator id> not found!' error message after running ideviceinfo command

Tags: ios, simulator

- Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
- Mojave Version 10.14.4 (18E226)

Steps which I am making:
 1. Launch iOS simulator using Xcode.
 2. Open terminal and run `ideviceinfo -u :

```
ideviceinfo -u 175669E4-93EE-413A-83A0-2FEE6B419826
```

3. Getting result:
   `ERROR: Device 175669E4-93EE-413A-83A0-2FEE6B419826 not found!`

Other guys get such answer in terminal after repeating my steps:

```
ideviceinfo -u BFD70ACE-3786-4BEE-B76D-D8D072EBAAC1
Usage: ideviceinfo [OPTIONS]
Show information about a connected device.

  -d, --debug       enable communication debugging
  -s, --simple      use a simple connection to avoid auto-pairing with the device
  -u, --udid UDID   target specific device by its 40-digit device UDID
  -q, --domain NAME set domain of query to NAME. Default: None
  -k, --key NAME    only query key specified by NAME. Default: All keys.
  -x, --xml     output information as xml plist instead of key/value pairs
  -h, --help        prints usage information

  Known domains are:

  com.apple.disk_usage
  com.apple.disk_usage.factory
  com.apple.mobile.battery
  com.apple.iqagent
  com.apple.purplebuddy
  com.apple.PurpleBuddy
  com.apple.mobile.chaperone
  com.apple.mobile.third_party_termination
  com.apple.mobile.lockdownd
  com.apple.mobile.lockdown_cache
  com.apple.xcode.developerdomain
  com.apple.international
  com.apple.mobile.data_sync
  com.apple.mobile.tethered_sync
  com.apple.mobile.mobile_application_usage
  com.apple.mobile.backup
  com.apple.mobile.nikita
  com.apple.mobile.restriction
  com.apple.mobile.user_preferences
  com.apple.mobile.sync_data_class
  com.apple.mobile.software_behavior
  com.apple.mobile.iTunes.SQLMusicLibraryPostProcessCommands
  com.apple.mobile.iTunes.accessories
  com.apple.mobile.internal
  com.apple.mobile.wireless_lockdown
  com.apple.fairplay
  com.apple.iTunes
  com.apple.mobile.iTunes.store
  com.apple.mobile.iTunes

Homepage: <http://libimobiledevice.org>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? libimobiledevice is installed. 'ideviceinfo -u ' command works correctly with real iOS device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ideviceinfo` (and the other utilities from libimobiledevice) only work with real, physical devices connected to your computer using a USB cable, or over WiFi. They don't work with simulators.

You can list the UDID of all devices with which you can interact via libimobiledevice by running `idevice_id -l`.

Comment: Yes, but why my terminal output (ERROR: Device ... not found) differs from default output?

Comment: The other guys are using an older version of ideviceinfo which prints an error if the UDID you specify is not exactly 40 characters long. That restriction was lifted when newer iOS devices started using a new UDID format. [This commit](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/commit/b34e3435c21d06b3e5a4e7b5246fb6ddb6641a9f#diff-b551d43f87ae95b515ebc091354f45c3) has all the details.